# Netty Threading Model

Tags: multithreading, netty

I have a use case wherein I want to make sure that the IO worker thread is always accessing a given buffer, which would be used to write the message received from the client, to make some of my data structures lock free. I was wondering if I could use Netty IO worker's thread ID as a unique identifier to maintain the association between the IO worker thread and the buffer context. Let me know if there are alternate ways to looking at this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that FastThreadLocal is a good choice for my use case. Thanks!